# Instanciar classe como sendo property de outra classe

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho duas classes criadas dentro do mesmo `namespace`, sendo:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int idPessoa { get; set;}
    public string nome { get; set;}
}

public class PessoaFisica
{
    public Pessoa pessoa { get; set;}
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string rg { get; set; }
}
```

Porém quando tento usar a classe `PessoaFisica`, recebo a mensagem de erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Como faço para instanciar a classe `Pessoa` dentro da classe `PessoaFisica` sem ter que usar o operador `new`?

As classes 'Pessoa' e 'PessoaFisica', têm a função de DTO. Consequentemente, serão usadas por outras classes das regras de negócio para popularem os DataGrids de cadastro de fornecedores, clientes e etc.

Answer (score 2):

Pode instanciar uma nova Pessoa no constructor de PessoaFisica:

```
public PessoaFisica()
{
    pessoa = new Pessoa();
}
```

Caso não queira que o utitlizador de PessoaFisica altere a propriedade pessoa, poderá mudar o Setter para private.

```
public Pessoa pessoa {get; private set; }
```

Assim garante que a propriedade apenas pode ser alterada por si.

Comment: Deu certo, mas trabalhando assim, o DataGrid é preenchido mas não exibe os dados...

Comment: Não existe menção a uma DataGrid na pergunta. Porque não actualiza a pergunta com a questão da DataGrid e explica-nos qual o objectivo da DataGrid e qual a sua ligação à PessoaFisica?

Comment: @Omni, atualizei a pergunta conforme sua sugestão. Ajuda?

Comment: @user8433 sim ajuda. Tal como o Crood perguntou, os campos de pessoa fisica foram populados? Tem de ter em conta que por default propriedades do tipo string são nulas, ou seja, na DataGrid os campos vão aparecer vazios. Experimente dar um valor a cpf e rg quando cria a lista que popula a DataGrid e veja se os valores dados aparecem.

Comment: @Omni, vou proceder conforme a sua sugestão e tão logo eu tenha o resultado, posto aqui. Por enquanto obrigado.

Comment: @user8433 mais uma sugestão, se tentar e mesmo assim não conseguir, edite a questão e coloque o código em que faz a atribuição da datasource da DataGrid.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo de codificação quando `Pessoa` está agregado a `PessoaFisica`.

*Normalizando*

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int IdPessoa { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaFisica
{
    public PessoaFisica()
    {
        //INSTANCIANDO NO CONTRUTOR
        this.pessoa = new Pessoa();
    }
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    public Pessoa Pessoa
    {
        get { return pessoa; }
        set { pessoa = value; }
    }        
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Rg { get; set; }
}
```

---

*Criando uma lista de `PessoaFisica`*

```
IList<PessoaFisica> PessoasListaFisica = new List<PessoaFisica>();

PessoasListaFisica.Add(new PessoaFisica()
{
    Pessoa = new Pessoa() { IdPessoa = 1, Nome = "Pessoa1" },
    Cpf ="12345678900", 
    Rg = "147852369SSP"
});
PessoasListaFisica.Add(new PessoaFisica()
{
    Pessoa = new Pessoa() { IdPessoa = 2, Nome = "Pessoa2" },
    Cpf ="00987654321", 
    Rg = "963258741SSP"
});
```

---

Utilizando a lista de `PessoasFisica` no `DataGridView`

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = PessoasListaFisica.Select(s => new
{
    s.Rg, 
    s.Cpf, 
    s.Pessoa.IdPessoa, 
    s.Pessoa.Nome
}).ToArray();
```

*Resultado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: assim que testar o seu exemplo, posto o resultado. Por enquanto muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tentei usar o seu exemplo mas estou recebendo essa mensagem de alerta 'Method must have a return type'. O métodopublic PessoaFisica()
    {
        //INSTANCIANDO NO CONTRUTOR
        this.pessoa = new Pessoa();
    } é do tipo void mesmo?

Comment: @user8433 o método que refere é o constructor de PessoaFisica(), não tem tipo de retorno.

Comment: Não tem retorno, é um método construtor, ou seja, será executado na instânciação da classe PessoaFisica();. Se ta com dúvida no exemplo ?

Answer (score 1):

O mais recomendado nessa situação é criar uma herança de pessoa em pessoa física.

Algo como:

```
public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
```

Mas caso queira trabalhar sem herança você precisa instanciar a classe pessoa no construtor de pessoa física.

Na sua classe pessoa adicione um método construtor.

```
 public PessoaFisica()
 {
     pessoa  = new Pessoa();     
 }
```

Comment: instanciei a classe Pessoa dentro da classe PessoaFisica e deu certo... o único problema é que ao definir o DataSource do meu DataGrid a linhas são preenchidas mas sem aparecer os valores.

Comment: @Crood, populei sim.

Answer (score 1):

Você vai ter que instanciar a classe Pessoa, você pode fazer isso no GET.

```
 public class Pessoa {
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaFisica {
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    public Pessoa Pessoa {
        get {
            if (pessoa == null)
                pessoa = new Pessoa();

            return pessoa;
        }
    }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string rg { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tentei fazer como sugeriu, mas dessa forma o problema persiste.